# Measurements for shapes disappeared

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can't seem to find any help for this simple problem. When drawing shapes in Illustrator I used to get live measurements of the shape next to my cursor. Sort of like this crude mockup I attached. For whatever reason this feature is gone and I can't turn it on again! Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to have Smart Guides enabled for the little box with dimensions to show.  The toggle to switch them on/off is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. You may have accidentally hit it.

Comment: Also in Preferences> Smart Guides make sure the tick box for Measurement Labels is on.